# hdparm will not set spindown for disks 14.04 server

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, disk-management, spindown

I have 4 HDD, one WD and 3 Identical generic brands.
I have edited /etc/rc.local to change hdparm -B to 127 for the 3 generic drives (WD is unsupported and probably handles itslef) and -S to 180 for all 4 drives.
After reboot 
`hdparm -B /dev/sd*`
 shows 127 for the 3 drives, however 
`hdparm -S /dev/sd*`
 returns:

```
-S: bad/missing standby-interval value (0..255)
```

for all 4 drives.
`hdparm -S180 /dev/sd*` gives:

```
/dev/sd*:
  setting standby to 180 (15 minutes)
```

however `hdparm -S /dev/sd*`
again returns:

```
-S: bad/missing standby-interval value (0..255)
```

I have searched for a solution but am at a loss as to how to make the drives spindown. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
hdparm -S 242 /dev/sd[a-d]
```

Sets spindown to 1 hr.